# How to indent html code examples

Tags: html

I have a website or a html page and I want to indent my code for my visitors to see. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
&lt;html>
&lt;body>
&lt;p>
hi
&lt;/p>
&lt;/body>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

In html, is there a way to indent a block code without using a lot of &nbsp ; , like the <blockquote> tag. this way, I can use something like this:

> <html>
>
> > <head>
> >     &lt/head>
> >     <body>
> >
> > > <p>
> > >     
> > >     Hi
> >
> > </p>
>
> </body>

</html>
Using:

```
<blockquote>
&lt;html>
<blockquote>
&lt;head>
&lt/head>
&lt;body>
<blockquote>
&lt;p>
<blockquote>
Hi
</blockquote>
&lt;/p>
</blockquote>
&lt;/body>
</blockquote>
&lt;/html>
```

I was wondering if there was a better way to indent blocks of code. If not, I was wondering if there was a way to use css to change it so there is no line on the side and it looks just link a normal indent to the user.

Comment: I would ease my life by using the beautiful [prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pre` tags to make preformatted text which can be indented via normal spaces/tabs.

```
<pre>
    &lt;html>
        &lt;head>&lt;/head>&lt;body>
            &lt;p>
                Hi
            &lt;/p>
        &lt;/body>
    &lt;/html>
</pre>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k55rcdgt/)

Comment: thanks, I never knew that you could indent freely in a pre element

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with CSS. The text-indent property specifies the indentation of the first line in a text-block. Try;

```
blockquote  {
    text-indent: 50px;//define indent in pixels
}
```

Here is a demo http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text-indent